# PuTTY: pass parameter to .sh file

Tags: shell, putty

Is there a way to pass parameter to shell script which is run using PuTTY, i.e.:

```
putty -ssh myIp -l root -pw pwd -m myscript.sh param1
```

If I do so, PuTTY will not run `myscript.sh`. How do I pass `param1` to it?

Comment: I think you want to use another tool in that family, `plink` . Good luck.

Comment: See also a very similar question [Run shell script (with parameters) on Windows command line via Plink](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462589/850848)

Comment: Thank you guys, plink is an option in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

From [Using PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m):

> 3.8.3.6
>
> `-m`: read a remote command or script from a file
>
> The `-m` option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section 4.18.1). However, the `-m` option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is known *not* to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.

I.e., `-m` option *expects to be given a file name*, so you can put static parameters inside the file, but you can't pass them on the command line, sorry...